# How to use store procedure to update column by using existing column value

Tags: sql-server

I am new to store procedure and I don't know how to use it. My question is how can I update my column by using existing column value by adding some constant string to it.

Example:
my table :--

```
NAME  NewName
Jay
Amit
```

I want to write a store procedure to access name value and add constant String "Hi" to every name and insert that new name into "NewName" column. I am using SqlServer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddHiToName
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [my table]
    SET NewName = Name + 'Hi'
END
GO
```

Execute the procedure:

```
EXEC AddHiToName
```

---

Bonus - if you want to use a parameter to specify what string to add, instead of using a constant hardcoded value.

Create the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddStrToName (
    @StringToAdd nvarchar(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [my table]
    SET NewName = Name + @StringToAdd
END
GO
```

Execute the procedure:

```
EXEC AddStrToName 'Hi'
```

Comment: How i can pass "HI" msg as IN parameter to procedure?

Comment: @JayantJadhav Just added that part

Comment: If i want to access Name column from other table then it will work? means i am using "select Name form tableName" by replacing Name?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
update myTable set NewName = 'Hi ' + coalesce(Name, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET NewName = 'Hi ' + NAME
```

It's a simple UPDATE. No needs to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
CREATE PROC SetName
(
  @Name VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE myTable SET NewName = @Name + ' ' + ISNULL(Name, '')
END
```

Execute procedue:

```
EXEC SetName 'Hi'
```